# Cannot open Jupyter notebook in Windows 8.1

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I had Anaconda installed on Windows 8.1 and Jupyter notebook was working just fine with Julia and Python. I tried to install R kernel, however, it resulted in an error that some dependencies are needed, so I installed "m2w64-zlib" library in Anaconda then I installed R using this command "conda install -c r r-essentials" and I needed to update anaconda, so I did. After finishing all installations and updates Jupyter doesn't work. It just opens for a second and then switches off without opening the notebook in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I dont write code in "R" but Anaconda provides a few steps on how to get "R" working. Follow the steps in this link, Hope it helps:
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/r_language

Answer (score 0):

It works now fine.

I uninstalled ipython

```
    conda uninstall ipython
```

then installed Jupyter.

```
    conda install jupyter
```